# Can not get Databinding to work (I Have read many posts and can not figure out what I am doing wrong)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created this base class for INotifyPropertyChanged...

```
namespace BASECLASSES.HelperClasses
{
    public class NotifyPropChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


    /// <summary>
    /// The propertyChanged Event to raise to any UI object
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    /// <summary>
    /// The PropertyChanged Event to raise to any UI object
    /// The event is only invoked if data binding is used
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventArgs args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);

            handler(this, args);
        }

    }

}
```

}

I have created a ViewModel which implements the base class here...

```
  public class CheckoutVM : BASECLASSES.HelperClasses.NotifyPropChangedBase
{




    private string fullName ;

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return fullName; }
        set
        {
            if (fullName != value)
            {
                fullName = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("FullName");
            }

        }
    }






}   


}
```

}

In XAML I have defined a namespace for the class...

```
 xmlns:bcbcns="clr-Namespace:BASECLASSES.HelperClasses;assembly=BASECLASSES"
```

I have defined a window resource...

```
  <Window.Resources>
      <m:CheckoutVM x:Key="chkOutViewModel"  />
  </Window.Resources>
```

Set the DataContext to the main grid...

```
   <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource chkOutViewModel}}">
```

Set the path for label content to...

```
  <Label Name="txtContactCheckingOut"  Content="{Binding Path=FullName}"/>
```

Next I set the label with this code...

```
 List<GET_CONTACT_Result> contactResultList = modsqlContact.GET_CONTACT(contactID);
 CheckoutVM checkOutContact = new CheckoutVM();
 checkOutContact.FullName = contactResultList[0].cFULLNAME;
```

But the label is not set.

If I add a constructor to the ViewModel like this....

```
    public CheckoutVM()
       {
          FullName = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
       }
```

The label is set to XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX so the binding seems to be correct.

It is looking like the handler is always null. PLEASE HELP!!!! What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resources are available in the code behind through the `Resources` property, which is the merged dictionary of resources.  Your item will be available through the key that you've given it.  Assuming that your example code for setting the `FullName` property is in your Window code behind, the following code should allow you to update the value to the bound instance.

```
List<GET_CONTACT_Result> contactResultList = modsqlContact.GET_CONTACT(contactID);
var contact = (CheckoutVM)Resources["chkOutViewModel"];
contact.FullName = contactResultList[0].cFULLNAME;
```

Comment: Probably not doing everything the best way for MVVM. However this code solved my problem.

Comment: MVVM is a pill you have to swallow whole.  I would recommend researching and adopting one of the main stream MVVM tool sets if you are going to do a lot of WPF development.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on which MVVM tool set to use?

Comment: I've had success with reactive ui and mvvmlight

Answer (score 1):

The problem it that your checkOutContact is not the same instance of CheckoutVM as the one used in your control.

One way of solving this is to set the view model in your Window's code-behind. Something like this:

```
public CheckoutVM ViewModel
{
    get { return (CheckoutVM) DataContext; }
    set { DataContext = value; }
}
```

Then you remove the DataContext from your Grid. By default, the controls in your Window will take the same DataContext as your Window.

```
<Grid>
    ...
    <Label Name="txtContactCheckingOut"  Content="{Binding FullName}"/>
    ...
</Grid>
```

And you initialize your window like this:

```
YourWindow yourWindow = new YourWindow();
yourWindow.ViewModel = new CheckoutVM();
yourWindow.ViewModel.FullName = contactResultList[0].cFULLNAME;
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: You don't need to set data context in code behind - what you've suggested is the same as setting the datacontext on the window in Xaml. You should avoid code behind wherever possible.

Comment: If I don't set the viewmodel in code behind as suggested, how do I set my variable to the instance of the ViewModel that is defined in XAML.

Comment: @kidshaw. I agree with you that in a "pure" MVVM application you wouldn't need this code-behind. But since I don't know how everything is done in his application, this is a simple solution that should help him see where the problem is.

Comment: I'm not convinced you've got multiple instances. Set a breakpoint in your constructor. It will give you a means to count the number of instances being created.

Comment: @user3059155 You can set it like you did, it's just that if you need to access your ViewModel, you would need a reference to your control and get the DataContext from it.

Comment: I set a breakpoint on the constructor and there are two instances. One is being created on the load of the form another on the code.  CheckoutVM checkOutContact = new CheckoutVM();

Comment: "you would need a reference to your control and get the DataContext from it." Can you steer me in the right direction for a code example of this?